# Unable to commit/update - Three errors posted in log

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

We've been using a Tortoise SVN setup at our office for years now without issue. All systems are Windows 7 and the repository is located on a NAS drive. Tortoise SVN is fully up-to-date and was working without issue until this morning when the first update was attempted. The following error message appears in the log:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///Z:/NASDIRECTORY/repository'
Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
Unable to open repository 'file:///Z:/NASDIRECTORY/repository'
Can't open file 'Z:\NASDIRECTORY\repository\db\current': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get over this errors? I've looked online for hours and can't seem to find anything that will work.

Comment: If you navigate to the `Z:\ ` drive, are the files there? Does it work after navigating there?

Comment: Yes, I have full access to the drive and all of the files are in the repository. But it does not work after navigating there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you do have a backup. Otherwise you will need to repair the repository manually.

1. The local repository `Z:\NASDIRECTORY\repository\` is broken. It does not have `current` file under `\db`. That's a matter to investigate.
2. Simultaneous access of multiple clients via file:/// protocol, especially to NAS, is strongly discouraged. You should setup a server and access your repositories via HTTP(S) or svnserve at least.